# Java: design-pattern for building certain columns in certain order

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a table with N columns (up to 20-25). The list of columns (columns and their order) is set by user. So this list is unknown in code writing time.

I have the following solution:

```
class abstract AbstractColumnBuilder{

  public TableColumn buildColumnA(){...}

  public TableColumn buildColumnB(){...}

  public TableColumn buildColumnC(){...}

  public TableColumn buildColumn(String columnName){
     switch(columnName){
         case "a":return buildColumnA();
         case "b":return buildColumnB();
         case "c":return buildColumnC();
     }
     return null;
  }
}

class ConcreteColumnBuilder extends AsbtractColumnBuilder{

 public TableColumn buildColumnD(){...}

 public TableColumn buildColumnE(){...}

 @Override
 public TableColumn buildColumn(String columnName){
     switch(columnName){
         case "d":return buildColumnD();
         case "e":return buildColumnE();
         default:return super.buildColumn(columnName);
     }
  }
}
```

and the usage

```
List<String>columnNames=...
for(String columnName:columnNames){
   TableColumn column=builder.buildColumn(columnName);
}
```

However, I don't like this solution. First of all it seems to me it is not very good from perfomance point of view - we need to make long case check in loop. Secondly developer can forget to override buildColumn method.

Is there any patterns for such case?

Comment: So the columns are built differently depending on the letter, correct?

Comment: An enum with some abstract build method might be a solution, or some annotation on your buildColumnXXX and some reflection to build a map XXX -> method

Comment: @JDC  Yes, so reflection can be used by idea.

Comment: I would say that this is a typical usecase for the factory design pattern: http://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/

Comment: I am not a Java developer, but for composing objects/classes with extra functionalities it's better to use Mixins, here is what I've found for Java: https://github.com/SpongePowered/Mixin/wiki/Introduction-to-Mixins---Understanding-Mixin-Architecture In your case, when a developer would like to create a class composing functionalities with 3 other classes (to build columns) he would have to somehow inherit methods from all these classes. With mixins it's simpler.